# How do I rotate a node in scenekit based on the current camera angle

Tags: ios, camera, rotation, scenekit, quaternions

I'm currently working on a project where I want to be able to use UIPanGesture to rotate a node based on the current rotation of the camera. For example, a user is looking at the geometry attached to the node and decides to rotate it. Where normally, the geometry rotation would be based on (0, 0, 0) or (0, 0, 0, 0), I would like to be able to rotate along the y axis where the Y axis would be the axis would be perpendicular to the camera angle, thereby treating whatever the camera angle is as (0, 0, 0, 0). My original solution was to rotate the pivot point to match the camera angle, but I'm not seeing anything in the Scenekit documentation that allows me to rotate the pivot point at all, so now I'm a bit lost. Any advice I could get on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ^_^